# How to Update Redmine on Windows (Helicon Zoo)

Tags: iis-7.5, ruby-on-rails, redmine, web-platform-installer

Quite some time ago I installed Redmine 2.1.2.stable using [Helicon Zoo](http://www.helicontech.com/zoo/gallery/Redmine.html) feed. And it's been working great (minus multi-minute app pool warm up times).

What's the best way to upgrade to the latest version? The feed was last updated 2013-01-29 and is on 2.2.2, but I can't find any facility in the WebPI for upgrades.

Using SQLlite for storage, if it matters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up doing a backup of the database (file), configuration and attachments then doing a reinstall. Always fun behind the new mandatory corporate proxy. :/

Note that when the Helicon Zoo WebPI feed says "may overwrite" it means "Will delete everything". Also it creates a duplicate app pool, so be sure to delete the old one.

Answer (score 0):

I would consult the vendors website for this type of question.  It appears to have an active and well documented @ http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/boards

Redmine 2.1.2.

Answer (score 0):

I have just seen something that you can use to upgrade your Helicon Redmine instance.
In the root folder of the Helicon Redmine install folder there is a file called 'deploy_done.rb'. It seems to have a setting that specifies the Remdine version to use.
On line 25 (in my version):

```
  REDMINE = "2.3-stable"
```

According to the comments at the top of this file:

```
# Helicon Zoo module runs this script every time IIS application pool recycles.
```

If I look at the code that is in this file, it seems to download the specified version of redmine from github and then install it in the local folder if the 'app' folder is not found (i.e. a new deployment).
I tried it out today and found that I could do an upgrade by doing the following:

1. Back up your database, configuration, and attachments (just in case!)
2. Rename the 'deploy_done.rb' file to 'deploy.rb'
3. Change the redmine version specified in the new 'deploy.rb' file to a name of a tag that you want to upgrade to (from the list in https://github.com/redmine/redmine/releases)
4. Delete (or rename) the 'app' folder in the redmine site root.
5. Recycle your site's app pool and browse to the site.
6. The deployment process should now start!

If you want to get the latest version number of Redmine that Helicon Zoo deployments are using then you could just install the latest version to another location from WebPlatformInstaller (Helicon Zoo). Once you have done that you can look for the 'deploy_done.rb' or 'deploy.rb' file in the site root and copy it into your site as 'deploy.rb' instead of step 2 & 3 above.

NOTE: it seems that if it is quite a big upgrade then you may need to upgrade some of your gems to get it working (the deployment error message should tell you which ones).